# Is it possible to export folders in the "All users" to excel?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, microsoft-excel, multiple-users

I need to get a list of users that have logged onto a computer, i'm currently doing this at the moment by going into the Documents and Settings folder and copying and pasting the name of each folder(the persons username) into an Excel spreadsheet. Is it possible to export all of them into an Excel spreadsheet say for example? If not, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: This method only tells you a username within a domain, not the full username. E.g. `AcmeInc\Joe` would have just `C:\Documents and Settings\Joe`.

Comment: Yeah .. :) I'm only working within one domain so it matches :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will following command satisfy your needs?

```
dir /AD /B "C:\Documents and Settings" >> user.log
```

You can also type in the RUN: `compmgmt.msc`

The computer management console will appear. Right click on Users hive and select export. 
It will give you list of all users.

Comment: It would be great, the only problem is, is that I'm "UNC'ing" to a remote computer on the network, i have no idea how i would use that command for a remote pc! I've looked everywhere and can't find anything.

Comment: UNC - you mean you use a share path like \\pc\c$\Documents and Settings\ ? Just place it in the command prompt instead of the path i provided. If you have a share mapped to specific drive letter - just place this letter instead of C drive in the example above.

Comment: it's in the directory you have in the command prompt as default.
if you have C:\Documents and Settings\yourusername\
 this is the place to search for the file. Or it might be on your desktop. You can specify the location directly by using >> C:\user.log - it will be on your C drive.

Comment: Excellent! Works wonders! Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Comment: Note that this only works in English (and English-derived) versions of XP. `C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen` is the German equivalent. Locally, you can query the `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` variable.